# How to Python Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm tying to get into unit testing for python and I'm having trouble with finding a way to tackel the following problem ([source](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/)).

> We have two functions, is_prime and print_next_prime. If we wanted to
>   testprint_next_prime, we would need to be sure that is_prime is
>   correct, asprint_next_prime makes use of it. In this case, the
>   function print_next_prime is one unit, and is_prime is another.
>   Since unit tests test only a single unit at a time, we would need to
>   think carefully about how we could accurately test print_next_prime.

```
def is_prime(number):
    """Return True if *number* is prime."""
    for element in range(number):
        if number % element == 0:
            return False

    return True

def print_next_prime(number):
    """Print the closest prime number larger than *number*."""
    index = number
    while True:
        index += 1
        if is_prime(index):
            print(index)
```

How would you write a unit test for both of these methods? Unfortunately the source never gives an answer to this question.

Comment: The `is_prime` function's broken as it'll attempt to divide by zero.

Comment: Yes, that is true. This is just an example for setting up unit tests. It is meant to fail on that part.

Comment: The source has explained unit tests. Read that until the end, there is correct implementation of is_prime function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has been fixed at the later parts of that [blog](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/), first you have to define the `is_prime`

```
#primes.py

def is_prime(number):
    """Return True if *number* is prime."""
    if number <= 1:
        return False

    for element in range(2, number):
        if number % element == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

This is the unit test case for one case `test_is_five_prime`. There are other examples as `test_is_four_non_prime`, `test_is_zero_not_prime`. In the same way, you can write tests for other function `print_next_prime`. You could try in the same way.

```
#test_primes.py

import unittest
from primes import is_prime

class PrimesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for `primes.py`."""

    def test_is_five_prime(self):
        """Is five successfully determined to be prime?"""
        self.assertTrue(is_prime(5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining!